# ShowHide (shID) to show only one div at a time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show-hide

I'm currently working on a Bootstrap website. I'm new at jquery and Java, so I can't figure how to do this.

I have something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/PVLMX/2/

```
function showHide(shID) {
    if (document.getElementById(shID)) {
        if (document.getElementById(shID + '-show').style.display != 'none') {
            document.getElementById(shID + '-show').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            document.getElementById(shID + '-show').style.display = 'inline';
            document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

I'm Using the  ShowHide function on a menu that shows a gallery of pictures. I would like to be able to show one div at a time. In the example would be to hide the first content (of see more) when you press the second see more button, without having to click on "hide this content". I want to eliminate the "hide this content" button.

Does that make sense? sorry if I'm not clear and thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Changing a little bit your HTML and adding JQuery, you can achieve it in this way:

HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
  <p>This text is visible, but there is more.
    <a href="#" id="example-show" class="showLink">
      <br/>
      <br/>See more >></a>
  </p>
  <div id="example" class="more">
    <p>This text was hidden, now you see it</p>

  </div>
</div>
<div id="wrap">
  <p>This text is visible, but there is more.
    <a href="#" id="example2-show" class="showLink">
      <br/>
      <br/>See more >></a>
  </p>
  <div id="example2" class="more">
    <p>This text was hidden, now you see it</p>  
  </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$('.showLink').click( function() {

    $('.showLink').parent().next().hide();
    $(this).parent().next().show();

})
```

**Remember to add JQuery in your html head section**

Here's a Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PVLMX/13/

If you want to know more something about Jquery `parent()` and `next()`:

https://api.jquery.com/parent/

https://api.jquery.com/next/